# When do I not use USING clause and just stick with ON in some cases?

Tags: sql, join

So, I tried fixing this up it’s a self join (joining using the same table. In this case, the table name is populations and has a country_code and year record in it amongst others) exercise I came across;

```
SELECT p1.country_code,
       p1.size AS size2010,
       p2.size AS size2015
FROM populations AS p1
JOIN populations AS p2
ON p1.country_code = p2.country_code
AND p1.year = p2.year - 5;
```

I tried using **USING(country_code)** to replace that “ON” clause, but I got a syntax error… but it gave a result when I queried using the ON as seen in the above query. Would love to find out why

Comment: Rather than showing something else that did work, you should show the thing that didn't work.  And the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

As using doesn't support calculations you need to split the conditions.

But as you don't need USING you should keep your code, it is only a short cut

```
SELECT p1.country_code,
       p1.size AS size2010,
       p2.size AS size2015
FROM populations AS p1
JOIN populations AS p2
USING(country_code)
WHERE p1.year = p2.year - 5;
```

Comment: In this case `p1.country_code` can just be written as `country_code`. Prepending the table alias can be useful when doing outer joins, however.